# Why does Chrome display an Out of Memory error when the files used aren't larger than the amount of memory allocated per tab (4GB)?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a website that pulls data from javascript data files (json files that I changed to js files) and then displays them into an HTML table. The code is adapted from 
[here](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/populate-json-data-to-html-table-using-javascript.htm), and the table-generating part is essentially the same. The total size of all of the files is ~300 MB. However, when I launch the code in Chrome and watch Task Manager, the memory used by Chrome goes to ~4300MB before crashing and displaying the Out of Memory error. I have only experienced this with one dataset, which is 270 MB. The rest are <16 MB. [This is what the website looks like after I select the second largest dataset, which is ~15MB (correct).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyvoX.png)

I'm not sure if this error was caused from code errors or because of the file size.

Comment: A table for displaying data takes more memory than just the data itself. Nothing too unexpected about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a javascript generator function to control what code is displayed while you scroll through large files.